# How to check wheather mysql is intalled or not in mac machine?

Tags: mysql

I just wanna confirm wheather MySql is intalled in my mac machine or not. Actually, during its installation process I just messed up with the password configuration and after that I tried to reset its password but all to vain and I finally decided to uninstall it and do the installtion again from start. But before installing it again I just wanna confirm wheather the previous installation got cleared properlly or not. For unintalling mysql I have used following commands

`sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*`

Comment: That's strange, I have a downvote. Would the person who did this please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following command. If it says "*command not found*" it's not installed.

```
mysql -v
```

Comment: I think, executing this command from root directory or from any another (except the directory where mysql installed) would always say "command not found".

Comment: I have not found this to be the case, if I run this from the root and it is installed it will show. Have you run the command?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it said "command not found" even if my mysql server was running. But after searching bit about this I found that I need to set mysql's path as an environment variable so that machine be able to found the excutables and did this --- export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Now, Its not saying "Command not found". But overall this is not the exact solution to known whther mysql is properlly uninstalled or not.

Comment: Okay but your original question was 'I just wanna confirm whether MySql is installed in my mac machine or not.' so now you know it is not installed so doesn't what I wrote answer your question? If so mark it done. Thanks!

Comment: Not exact but a second step of solution. Anyways, I accepted it. Thanks !